# Finding point on a line a given distance from another point on that line, 3D

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two coordinates: $A(0.25, 0.0337, 0.5)$ and $B(0.3912, 0.1558, 0.3796)$

I would like to find the coordinates of a point $C$ along that line that is 0.1014 away from point $B$, but not between $A$ and $B$.

The equation for that line between $A$ and $B$ (going from A to B) is $r(t) = <0.25, 0.0337, 0.5> + t<0.1412, 0.1221, -0.1204>$

Or in parametric form:

$x(t) = 0.25 + 0.1412t$

$y(t) = 0.0337 + 0.1221t$

$z(t) = 0.5 - 0.1204t$

Using the distance formula, I would have:

$0.1014^2 = (x - 0.3912)^2 + (y - 0.1558)^2 + (z - 0.3796)^2$

I'm assuming I need two more sets of equations to solve for x, y, and z (one of which could be the line equation above), and that I'll get two sets of solutions; one giving the coordinates between $A$ and $B$, and the other giving a point outside of $A$ and $B$.

Unsure how to use the parametric equations, and what other equation I may need. Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your parametrized equations for $x,y,z$ along the line in terms of $t$ are correct, and it appears that $B$ lies on the line for some $t > 0$, while $A$ is obtained with $t = 0$, then all you have to do is plug in the equations $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ into your formula for distance from $B$, and set it equal to the distance you want, and this will give you a quadratic in $t$ that has two solutions, and you want the solution that has the maximum value of $t$. Then plugging this value of $t$ into $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ gives you your point.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll double check that my parametrized eqns are correct and give that a try. Thanks very much!